# CentOS 7, what happened to DNAT?

Tags: linux, centos, firewall, iptables

I am doing some firewall work on CentOS 7. My end goal is to essentially make the server's internal ip address is the same as the floating ip address assigned to it. I disabled firewalld and installed iptables-services.

/etc/redhat-release

```
CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
```

iptables v1.4.21

When running this script I get

> iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "SNAT"
>   as well as unknown option "DNAT"

My script is

```
#!/bin/bash
PRIVIP="107.170.40.128" # e.g., assuming this is the private IP address
FLOATIP="104.196.55.167" # e.g. assuming this is the floating IP address
echo "iptables"
echo "/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d ${PRIVIP}/32 -j DNAT -–to-destination ${FLOATIP}"
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d ${PRIVIP}/32 -j DNAT -–to-destination ${FLOATIP}
echo "/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ${FLOATIP}/32 -j SNAT -–to-source ${PRIVIP}"
/sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s ${FLOATIP}/32 -j SNAT -–to-source ${PRIVIP}
echo "arp"
/sbin/arp -i eth0 -Ds ${PRIVIP} eth0 netmask 255.255.255.255 pub
/sbin/arp -an
echo "sleep"
sleep 10
systemctl restart network
```

What happened to the DNAT and SNAT options that are in Centos 6?

Comment: I think you should replace `--to-destination` and `--to-source` with `--destination` and `--source` respectively.

Comment: /sbin/iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 104.196.55.167 -j DNAT --source 107.170.40.128
iptables v1.4.21: unknown option "DNAT"

Comment: Fwiw, DNAT works just fine on my CentOS 7 system.  You will probably get better answers if you ask this somewhere more appropriate, such as [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) or [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com).  StackOverflow is for programming-related questions.